# Solving for the exponent of a power sum

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Let $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$, be real positive numbers.

Is it possible to solve $t$ from the following equation, if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are known?

$$
x^t + y^t=z
$$
If an exact solution is not possible, are there good approximations?

The more general case of interest would be to find $t$ that satisfies
$$
\sum_i a_i^t b_i=c
$$
Assuming that $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c$ are all known. We also know that $\sum_i b_i=1$ and that $a_i>1$.

Comment: If x,y,z are known there is no "function", but an equation, where you solve for $t$. What do you mean though by "derive a function"?

Comment: If I may make another observation, the condition $\sum_i b_i=1$ does not hold for the $x,y,z$ in your "trivial" case . Perhaps you meant the product of $b_i$? Interesting question though..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake That's true, our actual case of interest is the bottom one. The top one seemed to me to most simple "toy" example. And perhaps if a solution for that one exists, it could be applied to the bottom one too. The top one seems so trivial... ><

Comment: Honestly I can't tell-though I am trying :-). My guess is that there is no closed form solution but that is just a hunch. I hope this question gets more attention though. It deserves it.

Comment: If there were a closed form solution, I'd have to imagine the Lambert W function or logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to find the answer through the Fixed-Point method.

$$x^t+y^t=z$$

$$x^t=z-y^t$$

$$t=\log_x(z-y^t)$$

From here, you can use $t_{n+1}=\log_x(z-y^{t_n})$.

Assume you know what $t$ is, approximately.  Use that as $t_0$.  You will note that $t_n$ will either converge or diverge from the correct answer for $t$.

If it diverges, try $t_{n+1}=\log_y(z-x^{t_n})$.  It might work, though it really depends on what the correct value of $t$ is and what $x,y,z$ are.

Also, if you have to deal with complex numbers, I will tell you that it may converge, even if there are complex numbers.

For the general case:

$$t_{n+1}=\log_{a_k}(\frac{c-\sum_ia_i^tb_i-a_k^tb_k}{b_k})$$

Choosing $k$ to be a value that makes the series converge.

**More ideas**

If we use the substitution $t=\log(u)$, we get

$$x^{\log(u)}+y^{\log(u)}=z$$

$$u^{\log(x)}+u^{\log(y)}=z$$

We can use this adjustment to try and solve for $u$, given $x,y$, we can make the base of the logarithm something that could be simplified.

We could also attempt the Fixed-Point method again:

$$u_{n+1}=\sqrt[\log(x)]{z-u_n^{\log(y)}}$$

If we let $\log(x)=x'$ and $\log(y)=y'$, then it is equivalent to solving a polynomial of the form $u^{x'}+u^{y'}=z$, which cannot be done for general and most certainly cannot be done for $x',y'$ that are not whole numbers.  Though, sometimes you may be able to simplify things.

Also, $u_{n+1}=\sqrt[x']{z-u_n^{y'}}$

Comment: Hm, how would I choose the base of the logarithm such that the resulting $x'$ and $y'$ are $\in\mathbb{Z}$?  And would that even help?

Comment: @Simple_Art An iterative solution wouldn't really be practical in this case. Numerical solutions are easy. Some sort of analytical solution, even if approximate is what we need.

How do you go from 
$$x^{log(u)}+y^{log(u)}=z$$
to
$$u^{log(x)}+u^{log(x)}=z$$

The latter looks possibly more easy to solve.

Comment: @Delphine It is simply a very tricky step:$$x^{\log(u)}=10^{\log(x)\log(u)}=u^{\log(x)}$$

Comment: @Delphine A similar step was made here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710011/solving-an-expression-containing-two-added-exponential-functions