# Solving an expression containing two added exponential functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have a problem solving the below equation with respect to $x$:

$0.6\cdot \exp(\frac{-40}{x})+0.4 \cdot \exp(\frac{10}{x})=1$

My problem is that I have two exponential functions which are added together, so I don't know if I should use the natural log in order to get an expression solved with respect to $x$, or what I should do to accomplish this. I hope someone can help me with solving the expression above, so that I get an expression for $x$

David

Comment: Notice that $0.6\cdot \exp(\frac{-40.001}{x})+0.4 \cdot \exp(\frac{10}{x})=1$ would not have been doable the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations which are sums of exponential functions do not show analytical solutions in general.

Your case seems among the particular ones since writing $y=e^{\frac{10} x}$ the euation writes $$\frac{0.6}{y^4}+0.4y=1$$ which, unfortunately reduces to a quintic polynomial which is not the most pleasant to solve (few quintic equations have analytical solutions - if they have, they tend to show many radicals).

Probably the easiest could be to look for the zero of $$f(y)=0.4y^5-y^4+0.6$$ If you graph the function, you could notice that the positive root is around $2.5$. So, using Newton method for example $$f'(y)=2y^4-4y^3$$ gives the iterative scheme $$y_{n+1}=\frac{8 y_n^5-15 y_n^4-3}{10 (y_n-2) y_n^3}$$ Using $y_0=2.5$, the interates will then be $$y_1=2.46160000000000$$ $$y_2=2.45898401374040$$ $$y_3=2.45897234660929$$ $$y_4=2.45897234637796$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

Now, from $y$ get $x$.

**Edit**

The solution of the equation can be expressed with radicals. Be ready for the monster $$y=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{25-\frac{16\ 5^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{65}-5}}+8
   \sqrt[3]{5 \left(\sqrt{65}-5\right)}}+\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\frac{25}{8}+\frac{5^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{65}-5}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[3]{5
   \left(\sqrt{65}-5\right)}+\frac{195}{8 \sqrt{25-\frac{16\
   5^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{65}-5}}+8 \sqrt[3]{5 \left(\sqrt{65}-5\right)}}}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer! I also have one more question regarding the equation above: Is it possible to get a result for the below equation given only positive y-values? $0.6y^{-4}+0.4y-y^{-2.8}$, or do we need negative y-values in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is $2.8$ coming from ? You have to restrict the search for positive $y$ since $y=e^{\frac{10} x}>0$ for any $x$.

Comment: Okay, thanks again.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Glad to be of some help.